# Working with JQuery UI Dialog and CSS float:left

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-float

I have a JQuery UI dialog with two columns of form elements.  I'm using CSS `float: left` to create the columns.  The problem is the dialog only shows a single column.  What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/CV9RG/1/

Comment: No, I wanted the customer to be in one column and the description in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You columns has `float:left` it means if they don't have enough space on the parent to stay side by side they break in a new line. You can set a width for the dialog to `auto` and fixed for your columns to make it fit:

```
$('#mydialog').dialog({ 
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  dialogClass: 'no-close',
  width : 'auto'
})
```

and CSS :

```
.select-col { float: left;width:250px}
```

See this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/CV9RG/11/**

Comment: Wow, that was so simple!  Thanks!